# Why soft deleted entities appear in query results?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, soft-delete

I am trying to implement soft deleting concept.

Here is my object:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $softDelete = true;

    ...
```

Soft delete is on.

Now, if I 'delete' a post, it gets a 'deleted_at' timestamp:

[image: description]

The problem is, when I search or just use `all()` to display the posts, the soft deleted items appears there. What is wrong?

Comment: can you post the code where you delete the objects and also where you're requesting them to display on the page?

Comment: thanks, i already solved the problem...i was using Fluent queries instead of Eloquent, that was the reason for this behaviour

Comment: For future visitors: [read this if you are using 4.2](https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=1766-laravel-4-2-soft-deletes-issue/0)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The *soft deleting* feature works when using Eloquent. If you are querying the results with *query builder* you will eventually see all the records trashed and not trashed.

It is not clear in the current docs of Laravel 4, but seeing that the concept of *soft deleting* just appears under [Eloquent ORM - Soft Deleting](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting) and not under Query Builder, we can only assume that: **soft delete only works with Eloquent ORM**.

Comment: I thought originally that my devs were using Eloquent as the queries mentioned the model name first like how the docs in Eloquent area of Laravel had like so: SomeModel:join('table2', 'column1', 'column2')
 and the queries in the QueryBuilder docs used DB::table specifically which we weren't using. But if you use joins using that kind of syntax then it will still include the softDeleted data so I had to painfully add ->whereNull('table1.deleted_at')->whereNull('table2.deleted_at') in my queries (i wish there was an alternate SoftDeletes plugin to puts into separate archiving tables/schema)

Comment: you have to use ->with() to do join eloquently

Answer (score 58):

Sometimes, you will get the `soft deleted` table entries with `get()` even with eloquent and `protected $softDelete = true;`.

So to avoid this problem, use

```
...->whereNull('deleted_at')->get();
```

For example, this query will fetch all rows including soft deleted.

```
DB::table('pages')->select('id','title', 'slug')
                                   ->where('is_navigation','=','yes')
                                   ->where('parent_id','=',$parent_id)
                                   ->orderBy('page_order')
                                   ->get();
```

So the proper method is,

```
DB::table('pages')->select('id','title', 'slug')
                                   ->where('is_navigation','=','yes')
                                   ->where('parent_id','=',$parent_id)
                                   ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                                   ->orderBy('page_order')
                                   ->get();
```

Answer (score 35):

There is a little trick using soft delete tables and queries in laravel:

When we create something like

```
$objCars = Car::where("color","blue");
```

The system executes something like that:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  cars
WHERE
  deleted_at IS NULL
AND
  "color" = 'blue'
```

So far, so good. But, when we apply the "orWhere" method, something funny happens

```
$objCars = Car::where("color","blue")->orWhere("color","red");
```

The system will execute something like that:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  cars
WHERE
  deleted_at IS NULL 
AND 
  "color" = 'blue'
OR
  "color" = 'red'
```

This new query will return all the car where deleted_at is null and the color is blue OR if the color is red, even if the deleted_at is not null. It is the same behavior of this other query, what show the problem more explicitly:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  cars
WHERE
  (
    deleted_at IS NULL 
  AND 
    "color" = 'blue'
  )
OR
  "color" = 'red'
```

To escape from this problem, you should change the "where" method passing a Closure. Like that:

```
$objCars = Car::where(
  function ( $query ) {
    $query->where("color","blue");
    $query->orWhere("color","red");
  }
);
```

Then, the system will execute something like that:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  cars
WHERE
  deleted_at IS NULL
AND
  (
    "color" = 'blue' 
  OR
    "color" = 'red'
  )
```

This last query, searches for all cars where deleted_at is null and where the color can be or red or blue, as we was want it to do.

Comment: Does anyone if this is still true in later versions of Laravel?

Comment: it's better to do ->whereIn('color', ['red','blue']) imo.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and nothing here helped me.

My problem was in my construct, I forgot to call the parent constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();

   //Rest of my code
}
```

Hope that help someone!

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5.2.44 added `withoutTrashed()` method to `SoftDeletingScope`. For example you can use something like this:

```
Post::withoutTrashed()->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested it in Laravel 5.6, You need to use SoftDeletes Trait in your model

> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Banners extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    //no need of this below line
    //protected $softDelete = true;
}
```

and when you query

> $banners = Banners::where('status', 1)->get();

it will not return soft deleted data.

Answer (score 0):

me solved join table with eloquent on softdelete - laravel 8

```
$query = Model_table_1::join('user', 'user.id', '=', 'table_1.user_id')
->join('table_2', 'table_2.id', '=', 'table_1.table2_id')
->join('table_3', 'table_3.id', '=', 'table_1.table3_id')
->join('table_4', 'table_4.id', '=', 'table_3.table4_id')
->select('table_1.id','table_1.name','table_1.created_at',
'user.name','table_2.name2','table_3.name3','table_4.name4')
->get();
```

use where in datables

```
$query = Model_table_1::join('user', 'user.id', '=', 'table_1.user_id')
->join('table_2', 'table_2.id', '=', 'table_1.table2_id')
->join('table_3', 'table_3.id', '=', 'table_1.table3_id')
->join('table_4', 'table_4.id', '=', 'table_3.table4_id')
->select('table_1.id','table_1.name','table_1.created_at','user.name','table_2.name2','table_3.name3','table_4.name4')
->where('table_1.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
->get();
```

use where in view

```
$query = Model_table_1::join('user', 'user.id', '=', 'table_1.user_id')
->join('table_2', 'table_2.id', '=', 'table_1.table2_id')
->join('table_3', 'table_3.id', '=', 'table_1.table3_id')
->join('table_4', 'table_4.id', '=', 'table_3.table4_id')
->select('table_1.id','table_1.name','table_1.created_at','user.name','table_2.name2','table_3.name3','table_4.name4')
->where('table_1.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
->first();
```