# Laravel SoftDeletes still returns records used in joins even when deleted_at is not null?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am querying a model with joins that have deleted_at not null but they still return in the results.

Ex: `posts` table joins `post_likes` table, both with soft delete.

```
Posts::join(
   'post_likes',
   'post_id',
   '=',
   'id'
)->get();
```

Comment: If you have a `Like` model and `likes` relationship, you don't need to join. Any reason you aren't using them? You're not querying any columns from `post_likes`, so `join` doesn't seem necessary here.

Comment: @TimLewis I simplified my problem to show the basic problem which I am facing. My code is much more generic, it automatically builds query based on url.

Comment: Joining tends to bypass a lot of Eloquent's built in functionality. You should leverage relationships instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why soft deleted entities appear in query results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041155/why-soft-deleted-entities-appear-in-query-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current workaround is to manually check within the join, obviosuly I would prefer this to be automatic though

```
Posts::join(
   'post_likes',
   function ($join) use ($model) {
      $join->on(
         'post_id',
         '=',
         'id'
      );

      if ($model->hasColumn('deleted_at')) {
         $join->whereNull('post_likes.deleted_at');
      }
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little too late, but here's another solution.

```
Posts::join('post_likes', function($q) {
    $q->whereNull('post_likes.deleted_at')
    ->whereRaw("post_likes.post_id = posts.id");
});
```